# A question on maximal operators on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d),$ let $\widetilde{M}f$ be the unrestricted maximal function
$$\widetilde{Mf}(x_0, y_0) = \sup_{Q}\frac{1}{|Q|}\int_Q |f(x,y)|\,dx\,dy.  $$
where the supremum is over all $Q=[x_0-k, x_0+k]\times[y-l, y+l]$ with $k, l>0$.
Let me also introduce the functions
$$M_1 f(x_0, y)=\sup_{k>0}\frac{1}{2k}\int_{x_0-k}^{x_0+k}|f(x,y)|\,dx,$$
and
$$M_2 f(x, y_0)=\sup_{k>0}\frac{1}{2l}\int_{y_0-l}^{y_0+l}|f(x,y)|\,dx$$

I would like to show first that
$\widetilde{M}f(x_0, y_0)\le M_1M_2 f(x_0, y_0)$ for all $(x_0, y_0)\in\mathbb{R}^2$.

After that, I would like to prove the existence of $C>0$ such that, for all $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$,
$$\|\widetilde{M}f\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}\le C \| f\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}.$$
Let me first note that we may write

\begin{aligned}
\widetilde{Mf}(x_0, y_0)&=\sup_{k, l>0} \frac{1}{4kl} \int_{y_0-l}^{y_0+l} \int_{x_0-k}^{x_0+k} |f(x,y)|\,dy\,dx \\
&=\sup_{k,l>0} \frac{1}{2l} \int_{y_0-l}^{y_0+l}  \frac{1}{2k}\int_{x_0-k}^{x_0+k} |f(x,y)|\,dy\,dx \\
&\le \sup_{k,l>0} \frac{1}{2l}  \int_{y_0-l}^{y_0+l} \sup_{k>0} \int_{x_0-k}^{x_0+k} |f(x,y)|\,dy\,dx \\
&=\sup_{l>0} \frac{1}{2l}\int_{y_0-l}^{y_0+l} M_1f(x_0, y)\,dy \\
&= M_2 M_1 f(x_0, y_0).
\end{aligned}
The same argument works to prove the same result with $M_1 M_2$ replacing $M_2 M_1$. I believe this should prove the first point.

For the second point, I am assuming that I should use the first result to show it. With repeated Cauchy-Schwarz, I am able to get
\begin{aligned}
\widetilde{M}f &\le M_1 M_2 f \\
&\le \sup_{k,l>0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{4kl}}\left(\int_{Q}|f|^2\,dx\,dy\right)^{1/2} \\
&=\sqrt{\widetilde{M}(|f|^2)},
\end{aligned}
but I don't believe this can show that $Mf\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: I think your proof of the first part is perfectly fine. For the second part you want to use the same idea on the outer integral (no C-S inequality): I'll omit the tilde to ease notation,

$$
\| Mf\|_{L^2}^2= \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} |Mf(x,y)|^2 \, dx dy \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} |M_1M_2 f(x,y)|^2\, dx dy,
$$
and now appeal to the boundedness of $M_i$ on the real line and Fubini-Tonelli again.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "boundedness of $M_i$ on the real line"? Thank you.

Comment: $M_i$ is a one-dimensional Hardy-Littlewood maximal function, applied to the $i$-th coordinate. As such we have, for a.e. $y\in \mathbb{R}$, $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} |M_1 g(x,y)|^2\, dx \lesssim \int_{\mathbb{R}} |g(x,y)|^2\, dx.$$

Comment: Ok, so if I expand the left-hand side, I obtain $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} |M_1 f(x_0,y_0)|^2\,dx_0 = \sup_{k,k'>0} \frac{1}{4kk'} \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} 1_{B(x_0, k)}(x) 1_{B(x_0, k')}(x') |f(x,y_0)|f(x',y_0)|\,dx\,dx'\,dx_0.$$ How do I get the right hand side from here?